# How to get UI designer window for AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to start AJAX coding but also want to be able to design user interface in a designer window (like in MS Visual Studio) by dragging widgets onto the work area. Is there any tool that would let me do that easily?

Right now I'm using Aptana 3. I've installed jQuery but got lost trying to get jQuery UI. Is there any other way to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ajax/widget/js libraries out there that will have their own component designer, and you can stop searching for free ones, there are none.

There is one that most people know about, and it's called Sencha Architect, for the super awesome Sencha ExtJS library. Beautiful widgets, outstanding designer app, brilliant documentation. And such things of course come with a price tag.

If you are willing to make an investment:

Sencha ExtJS: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/
Store for ExtJS: http://www.sencha.com/store/architect/
Sencha Architect: http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
Store for Architect: http://www.sencha.com/store/architect/

Other than this one, I've not seen any component/UI designer application for any js/ajax library.